# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated makes my app crash :(

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, ipad, crash

I'm creating an iPad app, and I have two classes: `NWRootViewController : UITableViewController` and `UINewFeedViewController : UIViewController`. In `NWRootViewController` I have an `UIBarButtonItem`, which, when tapped, pops up a modal view controller called `NWNewFeedViewController`:

```
// THIS CODE IS IN NWROOTVIEWCONTROLLER.M
// New Feed
-(IBAction)showNewFeedViewAction:(id)sender {
    [newFeedViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self presentModalViewController:newFeedViewController animated:YES];
}
```

This works fine. However, in the `NWNewFeedViewController`'s view, I have another `UIBarButtonItem` which does this when tapped:

```
// THIS CODE IS IN NWNEWFEEDCONTROLLER.M
// Buttons
-(IBAction)cancelAction:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When I tap this button, the app crashes with:

```
2010-04-10 12:39:46.703 News[580:207] *** -[NWDetailViewController cancelAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4741110
2010-04-10 12:39:46.705 News[580:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NWDetailViewController cancelAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4741110'
2010-04-10 12:39:46.705 News[580:207] Stack: (
    40878667,
    2458187017,
    41150267,
    40613142,
    40609810,
    2776006,
    4876265,
    2776006,
    3246293,
    3255055,
    3250242,
    2899304,
    2793965,
    2825287,
    49238396,
    40419388,
    40415304,
    49232029,
    49232226,
    2817505
)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cancel button has a target of your detail controller; you meant to target your new feed controller.  So check how you configured the cancel button.

Comment: Actually, you are totally right! This is because of my stupidity that I `always` connect everything to the wrong outlets in IB -_-. Thanks ^^

Answer (score -1):

Your app is trying to call an object that has already been released. Enable zombie objects as explained [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) to find out what object is trying to be accessed.

Comment: Mmm... doesn't seem to work. Also overriding `-(void)release` and use `NSLog` doesn't log anything, and Insruments also doesn't seem to tell anything about `NWNewFeedViewController`.

Comment: YEs, that's not what the error message you got was saying.  Totally different.  Although that's a useful debugging tip.